# Is undefinite derivative a functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

In functional analysis...Kreyszig page 103: "A functional is an operator whose range lies on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$".

I know that a definite integral is a functional.
But is a undefinite derivative a functional?

For example is $\frac{d}{dt}$ a functional?

$\frac{d}{dt}t^n=nt^{n-1}$ where $t$ and $n$ are real numbers. But unlike a definite integral, it doesnt give us a number untill we give $t$ and $n$ a number. Is undefinte derivative a functional?

Thank you for heloing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a functional. Your output is a function, not a (real or complex) number.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary to max_zorn's answer, the "definite" derivative, that is, $\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right|_{x = t}$ is a functional, since the output is a real number, and it obeys all the linearity laws.